# what could be the better time complexity for the below code?

Tags: time-complexity

```
Input: Array A consisting n distinct integers, and an integer k
Output: an integer l
l = 0
for i = 1 to n
  for j = 1 to n
    if A[i] == A[j] + k then l = l + 1
  endfor
endfor
return l
```

How to reduce the complexity lower than O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by sorting the list of values, then assuming k is positive, you know 2 things:

- in your inner loop, you only need to search from A[i+1] and up, as you know that only values after A[i] can be greater than A[i]
- you stop the searching process in the inner loop once A[j] > A[i]+k, as you know that all further values will also be greater than A[i]+k

For a small set of data, the overhead of the O(log(n)) search would probably result in the algorithm being more expensive than your n^2 approach. However, as the data grows, that overhead will decrease relative to the n^2, and the substantially smaller set of comparisons will give you an overall gain.

Obviously the same principle could be applied if k was negative, you just have to swizzle round some logic, or simply negate both k AND your values.

Also - just noticed, as your integers are distinct, you can also break out of the inner loop if you find a match, as you know there can only be 1 match per entry.

That's what I'd do anyway!

Edit: Here's some example code:

{
    Input: Array A consisting n distinct integers, and a positive integer k
    Output: an integer l
    A = sortascending(A)
    l = 0
    for i = 1 to n
        #calculate target value
        target = A[i]+k

```
    #iterate through remaining entries
    for j = i+1 to n
        if target == A[j] then
            #got a match, inc l then bail out
            l++
            break
        elseif target < A[j]
            #now impossible for any further data points
            #to match, so bail out
            break
        endif
    endfor

endfor
return l
```

}

-Chris

Comment: I also started with sorting.i tool the best running time merge sort O(N log N).But in the second step still I need two loops .How can I skip that .I could not find a way .Can you please illustrate how the second bullet will work without two loops may be a bit of pseudo code will help ..

Comment: well,I think I have got the answer @Chris.First BUild a BST then Search so it will take O(Nlog N ) +O(log N)

Comment: Hi. Sounds like you've made some progress - yes a BST will definitely help as an approach. To be clear, I wasn't suggesting you could entirely eliminate the inner loop - just that it could be very short, as the assumption that the list is ordered allows you to put an upper and lower bound on the number of values you need to check. How my suggestion compares to a BST will be very dependent on the data.

Comment: Just adding sample in answer

Answer (score 0):

well, I just have ended up with a good solution better than O(n2) I think.
First Build a BST O(N log N) 
and then Search O(Log N ).

Answer (score 0):

If I can use any data structures, I choose *hash-set* structure for storing distinct values. *Hash-set* can typically create with O(n) time complexity and can access with O(1) time complexity.

```
 B =hashset(A) // requires O(n) time
 for i = 1 to n
     if B.contains(A[i]+k) then l= l+1
 endfor // also requires n×O(1) = O(n) time
 return l
```

I think this code has O(n) time complexity.

Comment: well,when collision occurs  worst time complexity for hash table is O(N) in that case it will again rise up to O(N2) as you have one for loop

Comment: I think you have only considered best case scenario for Hash set

Comment: If we can use enough memory to reduce time complexity, collision rarely occurs. Optimal solution for this problem varies by the number of element the input array has or the range of integers. We can use bit vector to implement set theoretically.